# React Native & Cosmos DB - How to get them working together?

Tags: react-native, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

There seem to be no direct support for React Native through Cosmos DB SDK or npm packages. The JS package @azure/cosmos while works on React Native for the Web, but does not build for the native apps. It fails to build due to Cryto incompatibility.

While Resource Tokens can serve as a solution for authentication, but App still needs to interact with the DB resources using an API.
So, how to go around this? Is utilizing Azure Functions as a mid-tier the only workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need basic functionality like querying, creating new items etc, you can get the [react-native-azure-cosmos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-azure-cosmos) package.
However the functionality is a very limited subset of the full JS SDK.

There is no official SDK for now to target react native applications.
You will need to use an API App or Function app to interact with CosmosDB and call the HTTP endpoints from your device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kalyan. We actually ended up using the Cosmos REST API directly from the app.